# Is there a security problem with my registration PHP form?

Tags: php

I've designed a website which when you want to register you need a unique phone number and you can not register with a same number twice.
But today something strange happened and i saw that a user has registered 4 times with a same phone number but its impossible because me and other people have tested it before and it was okay so i need your help
By the way i am  not a pro developer so can it be kind of security problem like an attack?
this is my register code :

```
public function register()
{
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){
        $post_array = [];
        $post_array['first_name'] = htmlspecialchars($_POST['registerName']);
        $post_array['last_name'] = htmlspecialchars($_POST['registerLastName']);
        $post_array['phone_number'] = htmlspecialchars($_POST['registerNumber']);
        $post_array['father_name'] = htmlspecialchars($_POST['fatherName']);
        $post_array['securityQuestion'] = htmlspecialchars($_POST['securityQuestion']);
        $post_array['securityAnswer'] = htmlspecialchars($_POST['securityAnswer']);
        $this->registerCheck($post_array);
    }else{
        if (Auth::loginStatus() == false){
            require_once 'mvc/view/register.php';
        }elseif(Auth::isAdmin() == 'true'){
            header("Location:/admin/dashboard");
        }elseif(Auth::isUser() == 'true'){
            header("Location:/profile/dashboard");
        }

    }
}


private function registerCheck($post_array)
{
    
    $resultByNumber = UserModel::getUserByNumber($post_array['phone_number']);
    if ($resultByNumber == []){
        $post_array['uniqueNumber'] = true;
    }else{
        $post_array['uniqueNumber'] = false;
    }

    $security = new Security();
    $validator = new Validator($post_array,$security);
    $errors = $validator->validate();
    if ($errors == []){
        sendSmsCode($post_array['phone_number']);
        header("Location:/user/confirmNumber/".$post_array['phone_number']."/".urlencode($post_array['first_name'])."/".urlencode($post_array['last_name'])."/".urlencode($post_array['father_name']));
    }else{
        $_SESSION['formError'] = $errors;
        header("Location:/user/register".$string);
        die();
    }
}
```

and this is the code which checks phone number in validator class :

```
private function phone_number($value)
{
    if (empty($value)){
        $this->addError('phone_number','شماره تلفن نباید خالی باشد');
    }elseif (preg_match("/(\+989|09)(11|12|13|14|15|16|17|18|10|19|90|91|92|93|94|01|02|03|04|05|30|33|35|36|37|38|39|41|20|21|22|31|32|34)\d{7}/", $value) == false) {
        $this->addError('phone_number', 'فرمت شماره تلفن صحیح نمی باشد');
    }elseif ($this->data['uniqueNumber'] == false){
        $this->addError('phone_number', 'این شماره قبلا ثبت شده است');
    }
}
```

Comment: for `if ($resultByNumber == []){` you should be doing `if (empty($resultByNumber)){` also its only unique once you register, a bot could make way more then 4 calls at the same time with the same values

Comment: This is impossible to answer without seeing all the components that you're referring to in the code you posted. Please update your question accordingly.

Comment: ***a user has registered 4 times with a same phone number***
that could possibly be from submitting 4 times simultaneously, or in very quick succession. look into ways of mitigating that. one way is in the DB. you can make a unique index on the phone number field/column.

Comment: When does the number get registered in the database (for the purposes of what `UserModel::getUserByNumber` fetches)? If It's only *after* a SMS/other confirmation routine, then there's nothing stopping me from registering a hundred accounts in the meantime, and confirming them all in the end (in one go?!).

Comment: @Lawrence Cherone so what do you suggest for this to not happen?

Comment: @Ro Achterberg  ok i will do it

Comment: @loydg so that is enough to just make the number field unique?

Comment: @Markus AO after checking all the errors if there is no error like "same phone number" or "invalid phone number" it redirects to confirm page which send to user a confirmation code and if user enter the correct code it will insert into database

Comment: Yes, add a unique constraint and DB cant take the same values. Also `trim` so there aren't any spaces. Your `11|12|13|14|15|16|17|18|10|19|90|91|92|93|94|01|02|03|04|05|30|33|35|36|37|38|39|41|20|21|22|31|32|34` can be simplified to `[13]\d|9[0-4]|0[0-5]|41|2[0-2]`

Comment: Have your routine check for pending registrations as well, not just confirmed registrations, and as suggested by others, a unique constraint on the field for a final stop.

Comment: @Markus AO than you so much Markus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No seems attack, seems like the user click register button multiple times. You need to ensure that the database prevent this using "unique" constraints. Ex. if you are using mysql, you can add a unique index over the phone number column. see below

```sql
create unique index the_name_of_the_index
on the_table_name (other);
```

In the other hand, i have some suggestions to improve your code

1. After each redirect add an "exit;" to prevent that script continues running.
2. You no need to use htmlspecialchars filtering data from post. You need htmlspecialchars to display the data on the navigator.
3. To improve the legibility you may check for active sessions at the top, and create some helper methods

Let me show the suggested code

```
<?php

public function handleRequest()
{
    $this->redirectLoggedInUser();

    if ($_SERVER[ 'REQUEST_METHOD' ] == "POST") {
        $this->register();
    } else {
        $this->showRegistrationForm();
    }
}

protected function register()
{
    $userData = [];

    $userData[ 'first_name' ]       = $_POST[ 'registerName' ];
    $userData[ 'last_name' ]        = $_POST[ 'registerLastName' ];
    $userData[ 'phone_number' ]     = $_POST[ 'registerNumber' ];
    $userData[ 'father_name' ]      = $_POST[ 'fatherName' ];
    $userData[ 'securityQuestion' ] = $_POST[ 'securityQuestion' ];
    $userData[ 'securityAnswer' ]   = $_POST[ 'securityAnswer' ];

    $this->validate($userData);

    // save the user without number confirmation
    $userid = UserModel::save($userData);

    // then, on the confirmNumber page, you send the sms and
    // collect the verification code
    // you can simplify the url because now you have the userid
    // and can get the user info in confirmNumber controller
    // you get more control in this way, if the user reloads the page
    // you could check the verification status
    $confirmPhoneUrl = sprintf("/user/confirmNumber/%s/%s/%s/%s",
        urlencode($userData[ 'phone_number' ]),
        urlencode($userData[ 'first_name' ]),
        urlencode($userData[ 'last_name' ]),
        urlencode($userData[ 'father_name' ])
    );

    header("Location: ".$confirmPhoneUrl . '?userid=' . $userid);
    exit;
}

protected function showRegistrationForm()
{
    require_once 'mvc/view/register.php';
}

private function redirectLoggedInUser()
{
    if (Auth::isAdmin()) {
        header("Location: /admin/dashboard");
        exit;
    } elseif (Auth::isUser()) {
        header("Location: /profile/dashboard");
        exit;
    }
}

private function validate($post_array)
{
    $security  = new Security();
    $validator = new Validator($post_array, $security);
    $errors    = $validator->validate();

    if ($errors) {
        $_SESSION[ 'formError' ] = $errors;

        header("Location: /user/register");
        exit;
    }
}
```

And the validator class modification

```
<?php

private function phone_number($value)
{
    if (empty($value)) {
        $this->addError('phone_number', 'شماره تلفن نباید خالی باشد');
    } elseif (preg_match("/(\+989|09)(11|12|13|14|15|16|17|18|10|19|90|91|92|93|94|01|02|03|04|05|30|33|35|36|37|38|39|41|20|21|22|31|32|34)\d{7}/",
            $value) == false) {
        $this->addError('phone_number', 'فرمت شماره تلفن صحیح نمی باشد');
    } else {
        $userByNumber = UserModel::getUserByNumber($value[ 'phone_number' ]);

        if ($userByNumber) {
            $this->addError('phone_number', 'این شماره قبلا ثبت شده است');
        }
    }
}
```

Notice that you need to modify the confirmNumber to send the sms

Comment: thank you so much for your help. and about your suggested codes, they are really great and so useful for me. thanks again